# Can you embed videos in answers on "Teams"?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

I understand that there are certain Stack Exchange sites that allow embedding of videos in answers, but is it possible with the Teams product?

Trying to evaluate if this will be a good internal wiki tool for us since we have many video walkthroughs.

Comment: @ThomasMattimore well, so ask other team member who has enough reputation on Stack Overflow (5 rep is enough) to post this on Meta Stack Overflow. Since you're both on same team and MSO doesn't have its own rep mechanism, it really doesn't matter who post it. :)

Comment: The feature isn't disabled on most sites due to performance reasons, it's disabled because we do _not_ want to take steps toward needing to deal with posts that consist mostly of just a video on the public Q&A sites. For teams, that's not an issue - teams regulate their own content. What remains is if the individual site settings needed to turn it on apply to teams, which we'll find out as soon as a dev chimes in.

Comment: I don't belong to any *Teams™*, but are StackSnippets® available there? If so you could probably workaround this with `<!-- begin snippet: html -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <video src="your_video.mp4" controls></video>

<!-- end snippet -->`

Answer (score 8):

We could *probably* enable it for *public* YouTube videos, but I'm not certain that would work well for your purpose. I don't think the existing embedding feature (which is a post processor on our end that just translates links to embedding code) would work for private YouTube videos.

Uploading of videos isn't a feature we're likely to support soon. What I recommend you do is reach out to us privately, and let us know more about your need and where this stuff is currently hosted, and we'll see if we can build something to accommodate it if we can fit a broader use case.

Comment: The existing implementation should work for unlisted videos, though, which *might* be enough at least for some use cases. (In fact, I know it works, since I have an [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/321665) on gaming.SE that includes an unlisted YouTube video.)

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to embed videos in Teams posts like it is [on some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104189/295232), though small GIFs (< 2 MB) would work via the standard image embedding – Teams images are hosted on the Team itself, not imgur.com, so they are still private.

Of course, since most Team members will have access to internal resources within your company or organization, you can always post links to them.

Comment: I think he's talking about YouTube (albeit, probably private channels).